# How to add a link in PDF pages using iTEXT to launch an external resources like audio , video etc

Tags: itext, pdf-annotations

I'm using **iText-5.0.1** library - ‘PdfAction’ Class which defines an action that can be triggered from a PDF file.

Currently, I am using PdfAction **gotoLocalPage()** method and successfully able to Create a GoTo action to an internal page of PDF using following code.

```
PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(link.getPhysicalvalue(), d, stamper.getWriter());
over.setAction(action, llx,lly,urx,ury);
stamper.close();
```

Now, I'm trying to add a icon containing link (referenced by a audio or video URL) in PDF to launch an external resources like audio , video etc. using iText.

I tried below code for the same but unable to add a link in PDF to launch an external resources.

```
Rectangle linkLocation = new Rectangle(x, y, x + w, y + h);
    PdfDestination destination = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
    PdfAnnotation link = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(),
            linkLocation, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,
            new PdfAction("http://www.google.com")
            );
    link.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0, 0, 0));
    stamper.addAnnotation(link, 1);
    stamper.close();
```

Can anyone please guide how to create/add a link to launch external resources like any mp3, image, video URL, etc.
Thanks.

Comment: So you are essentially asking for a book, tutorial, manual, example code,...? Have you looked at developers.itextpdf.com? And please use iText 5.5.10.

Comment: I am looking for some available example code.